Get route path for rails route?
I am working on some Rails internals and have a place where given a ActionDispatch::Journey::Route object, I need the path prefix.
If I run this:
pp route.path.spec.to_s

I get this:
/my-endpoint(.:format)

But the full path is missing and I need the stuff in the parenthesis omitted, so with this route being mounted at /api, I need this in stead:
/api/my-endpoint


The methodology you are using ( route.path.spec.to_s) works correctly so you need to determine why you believe the api portion should be there. You can scrap the (.:format) fairly easily after the fact.

if your route is defined in an engine, then /api is a separate route that's handled by the main app, the rest is forwarded to the engine which becomes its own route. depending on where in the internals you're, you probably need access to the request object: "#{request.script_name}/#{request.route_uri_pattern}"
